# Crystal Report export to excel data in wrong column due to null fields

Tags: crystal-reports, export-to-excel

I try to export a crystal report to excel. The report is list of data. Some date may be omitted but, of course, the column order must be respected. But with an empty field all the data are shifted to the left and the column is not right any more. 
How can I setup the crystal report to add empty cell for an empty data field ?

Answer (score 2):

I put a blank text file field same height and width Over the field with the issue. 
Then moved the field to the back.   It worked, all data is aligned correctly in the Excel spreadsheet.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to experiment with the report's Excel-export options (File | Export | Report Export Options...).  Consider 'Data Only (XLS)'.

I usually use TTX format, as it seems to work better than XLS.

Comment: 'Data Only (XLS)' solved the same problem for me, thanks Craig

Answer (score 0):

Try add export option .ExcelUseConstantColumnWidth = false;